# phpMyAdmin token authentification system

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I recently had the idea to create a login system to PhpMyAdmin with a token created from login credentials stored in a database.
The url would look like this :

```
pma.example.com/index.php?token=WCxuFWj1QtGGapZhfSPS9Eo1Q9q666sR
```

The token contains 32 randomly generated alphanumeric characters.

So I have an API made in Python with Flask which communicates locally with PhpMyadmin and the different applications with which has two routes:

1. `127.0.0.1:4040/api/v1/create_token` [POST] This request has as JSON argument `database_host_id` for the MySQL host ID to connect defined in PhpMyAdmin configuration file, `database_username` which is as written the database user to connect and finally `database_host` which is the database password. The response have an `token` argument for the client to receive the new generated token.
   The JSON sent and received should look like this :

```
JSON received by the API :
{
  "database_host_id": 1,
  "database_username": "pma",
  "database_password: "4wAyS8",
}

JSON sent to the client:
{
  "token": "WCxuFWj1QtGGapZhfSPS9Eo1Q9q666sR"
}
```

2. `127.0.0.1:4040/api/v1/get_database` [POST] This request has a JSON argument `token` to know from which token to retrieve the connection information. So the response will have all this information along with `database_host_id`, `database_username` and `database_password`. The JSON sent and received should look like this :

```
JSON received by the API :
{
  "token": "WCxuFWj1QtGGapZhfSPS9Eo1Q9q666sR"
}

JSON sent to the client :
{
  "database_host_id": 1,
  "database_username": "pma",
  "database_password: "4wAyS8",
}
```

It's nice to have an API but if you don't use it, it's useless, so I searched in the source code of PhpMyAdmin how the authentication system worked.

I could understand that :

- `/libraries/common.inc.php` This script would at runtime use what is called an `AuthPlugin` with this piece of code to then be used as a login interface by the various classes:

```
$auth_plugin = Plugins::getAuthPlugin();
$auth_plugin->authenticate();
```

- I went to see what an `AuthPlugin` was by looking at the different functions associated with this class. I deduced that all the files in `libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth` were connection plugins and allowed to define the different connection methods for MySQL hosts that we define in the PhpMyAdmin configuration file with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']`. Knowing that the default authentication type was [Cookie](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_auth_type), I went to see the contents of the file `librairies/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php`.

So now I had to modify the `AuthenticationCookie.php` script so that when `token` was contained in the URL, it could retrieve the information from the API and then use it to connect to the database associated with that token.

And that's where I get stuck because despite my PHP basics, I can't get what I'm doing to work. I could notice despite my attempts that when I retrieve the token from the URL, it was not at all what was defined, it was as if it was encrypted.

So here are my questions:

1. Should I encrypt the password even though the API only communicates locally?
2. Shouldn't I just use the [SignOn](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#signon-authentication-mode) connection method for my MySQL host?
3. Is it safe to do what I am trying to do?

Information:

- PhpMyAdmin version: 5.1.3

I would appreciate any kind of help in my reasoning to do or for any answers to my questions

Comment: Why do you return the `database_password`?  The client does not need it, it has a token that should be used to access the database.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the phpMyAdmin authentication system? Or actually make a certain way to log into mySQL, or what? The purpose of all this is is not very clear.

Comment: @Luuk I return it because the request is made by AuthPlugin and so it need the requested password

Comment: @ADyson It's true that I didn't really write the reason of all this, but to answer your question the goal is to make an additional way to connect to PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally ended up making a SignOn script associated with my server that gets the token from the URL, asks the API for the token information and then connects with it. It works perfectly.

```
<?php
/**
 * Single signon for phpMyAdmin
 *
 * This is just example how to use session based single signon with
 * phpMyAdmin, it is not intended to be perfect code and look, only
 * shows how you can integrate this functionality in your application.
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

/* Use cookies for session */

ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'true');
/* Change this to true if using phpMyAdmin over https */
$secure_cookie = false;
/* Need to have cookie visible from parent directory */
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', $secure_cookie, true);
/* Create signon session */
$session_name = 'SignonSession';
session_name($session_name);
// Uncomment and change the following line to match your $cfg['SessionSavePath']
//session_save_path('/foobar');
@session_start();

/* Was data posted? */
if (isset($_REQUEST['token'])) {
    $data = array(
        'token'=> $_REQUEST['token']
    );
    $payload = json_encode($data);
    $curl = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/v1/get_database');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    
    /* Store there credentials */
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = $response->database_username;
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = $response->database_password;
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_host'] = $_POST['host'];
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_port'] = $_POST['port'];
    /* Update another field of server configuration */
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_cfgupdate'] = ['verbose' => 'Signon test'];
    $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_HMAC_secret'] = hash('sha1', uniqid(strval(rand()), true));
    $id = session_id();
    /* Close that session */
    @session_write_close();
    /* Redirect to phpMyAdmin (should use absolute URL here!) */
    header('Location: ../index.php');
} else {
    /* Show simple form */
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' . "\n";
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Loading...</title>
</head>
<body>';

    if (isset($_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_error_message'])) {
        echo '<p class="error">';
        echo $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_error_message'];
        echo '</p>';
    }

    echo '
<h1>Loading...</h1>
</body>
</html>';
}
```

I know it's not finished but I plan to improve it. So this is the solution I found.

Comment: Where did you place this file?

Comment: @Nahid Same location as the config.inc.php file.